# Having trouble with simple awk script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, awk, pipe

This works in the command line:

```
awk -F, '$5>1900 {print $2}' presidents.csv
```

But I am not sure how to do it in an awk script.
This is what I have tried so far in the script.

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
if ($5>1900)
{print $2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWk script would be like,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {FS=",";}
{
if ($5>1900)
{print $2;}
}
```

That is, you need to enclose the if condition inside curly braces.

Comment: That is completely wrong. KannanMohan has the right answer (except for the useless semi-colons) and @larsks has it 100% correct.

Comment: How semicolons would make the answer wrong? Op uses the if condition.It would be possible to write without if condition. He's asking for how to rewrite the code to make it work.

Comment: semi-colons don't make it wrong they just add a bunch of useless characters, like if you put every symbol inside parens. Puting the condition inside an if statement inside the action part make it wrong. It's not how you write awk - awk scripts are written as `<condition> { <action> }`, not `<nothing> { if (<condition>) { <action> } }` and the OP deserves to know the right way to do it in awk.

Answer (score 5):

The stuff you have in single quotes:

```
awk -F, '$5>1900 {print $2}' presidents.csv
```

*Is* an AWK script.  Just stick that in a file:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
$5>1900 {print $2}
```

Answer (score 4):

AWK requires a `pattern` to search for and an `action` to be taken when it finds the pattern. Either `pattern` or `action` can be omitted but not both.

In your case first its a syntax mistake as you haven't enclosed your `action` within braces ( `{}` ) and so this will cause AWK to think both `pattern` and `action` got omitted. We can use relational expression as `pattern` in AWK and so instead of using an `if` statement you can use the relational expression as below.

```
$ cat test.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=",";
}

$5 >= 1900 {
    print $2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a shell script that runs your awk command you can put the following into a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '$1>1900 {print $2}' $1
```

To make it so you can actually execute the script, you can run:

```
chmod +x ./script_file_name_here
```

Then you can run

```
./script_file_name_here presidents.csv
```

and have the same thing happen.